# ¿Como aplicar filtros en DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

El objetivo de la funcion, es poder dividir dos valores, el primer extraido de una Base de datos de fomra simple, y el segundo, debe cumplir una condicion, de lo contrario, buscar en otro lado.
Esto tengo hasta el momento, que en parte funciona:

```
%_TD_MD_IND = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('DB'[TOT DIST]),
    IF(MAX('REF 2023 (2)'[TOT DIST]), MAX('REF 2023 (2)'[TOT DIST]), (MAX(PROM_JUG[TOT DIST]))),
    BLANK()
    )
```

Lo que estoy intentado, es que el primer valor despues del IF **(MAX('REF 2023 (2)'[TOT DIST])**, debe ser "mayor o igual" que el valor de otra columna:

```
%_TD_MD_IND = 
DIVIDE(
    SUM('DB'[TOT DIST]),
    IF(MAX('REF 2023 (2)'[TOT DIST]), (FILTER(ALL('REF 2023 (2)'[MIN]), 'REF 2023 (2)'[MIN] = SELECTEDVALUE('REF 2023'[MIN]) >= 80)), MAX('REF 2023 (2)'[TOT DIST])), MAX(PROM_JUG[TOT DIST]),
    BLANK()
    ))
```

No logro que la formula funcione.

Gracias